# How can I detect where kerberos authentication delays are occurring when impersonating a user?

Tags: .net, authentication, kerberos

In an application that impersonates another domain user for file system access, we're experiencing a 2 second delay from when `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate` is called to when the authentication for that user is actually done. This is only reproducible on the production machine (Windows Server 2008), not on our development machines (Windows 7). We verified that the delay happens **before** Kerberos authentication takes place by analyzing network traffic using Wireshark - the authentication only takes a fraction of the time, while the delay occurs beforehand.

What tools exist that will help to pinpoint the exact location/cause of this delay? Thanks!

**Breakthrough**: This only happens in a 64-bit process running on the production machine (the same code base compiled targeting x86 runs with no delays on production). But why? More research...

(Additional information will be added as it becomes relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not already using them, you'd almost certainly benefit from some of the tools in the [Windows SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027) suite of tools.  [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) might be a good start.  The basic idea is to trace what Windows and your application are doing and see what turns up.

Have you attached a debugger to the process?

The other thing to do is to identify other differences between the production and development machines.  Are there different versions of libraries in use? What about configuration? If you have a backup of your production server, can you recreate the problem there?

Comment: It ended up being caused by a Symantec tool (Backup Exec, I believe) injecting .dlls into loaded 64-bit assemblies (thank you Process Explorer). At first, building/deploying in 32-bit mode solved the problem. Later, we disabled the Symantec tool, and the problem went away with the 64-bit build. Thanks for the help!